# Finding a periodic orbit

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have given the following system of ODEs:
\begin{cases} x'= -y + x(r^4-3r^2 + 1) \\ y'= x + y(r^4-3r^2 + 1) \end{cases}
where $r^2=x^2+y^2$.
I have to find the equilibrium and ,using the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem, I have to show that there is a periodic orbit in the region $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2|0<|x|<1\}$. 
Now I showed that the only equilibrium is the origin (and from the Poincaré-Bendixson it follows that there is a periodic orbit) and in case I wrote the system in polar coordinates:
\begin{cases} \theta'= 1 \\ r'= r(r^4-3r^2 + 1) \end{cases}
How can I procede?

Comment: Along $r = \frac 12(\sqrt{5}-1)$ you have $\dot r = 0, \dot\theta = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider your dynamical system in polar coordinates:

$$\theta'= 1$$
$$r'= r(r^4-3r^2 + 1)$$

In theory, you can immediately discern the existence of a periodic orbit for $r = \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{5} - 1)$ as the second root of that expression for $r'$, but we want to use the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem to show it.

Consider the system at two $r$'s that are a little bit larger & smaller than $\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{5} - 1)$; say, at $r = \frac{1}{2}$ and $r = 1$.

For $r = 1/2$, we find that $r' = 5/32$, so trajectories at this radius tend to move away from the origin. For $r = 1$, we find that $r' = -1$, so trajectories tend to move towards the origin.

Therefore, the annulus region defined between these two radii is a trapping region, and there must be a periodic orbit somewhere inside of it as per the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem.